# fprintf prints data in wrong order

Tags: c, printf

I have program in C language which prints some data to standard output. I used `printf` for this but I need to save data to file as well so I changed it to `fprintf`. Problem is, that with using fprintf, the data are in wrong order, doesn't matter, if the output is stdout or file.

```
  if(...) {
    out = fopen(param.F, "w");
  } else {
    out = stdout;
  }

  // some code here
  fprintf(out, "a");
  // more code
  fprintf(out, "b");
  ....
```

Atfer this, output is always different. Sometimes it's

> acb

Sometimes it's

> cab

etc...I tried various combinations of setbuf and fflush but none of them helped.

EDIT: It might be important to know, that I use some `fork()` in my program but as I mentioned before, there's no problem when using printf.

Here's my output:

1: barber: checks

2: customer 1: created

3: customer 1: enters

5: barber: ready

6: customer 1: ready

4: customer 2: created

7: barber: finished

8: barber: checks

9: customer 2: enters

10: customer 1: served

11: barber: ready

12: customer 2: ready

13: barber: finished

14: barber: checks

15: customer 2: served

It should be ordered by numbers. The program has structure like this:

```
int main() {
  pid = fork();
  if(pid == 0) {
    // barber printfs
  } else if (pid > 0) {
    // customer printfs
  } 
}
```

Comment: Please post a simple test case with inputs and expected outputs that shows your problem.  Otherwise we're simply guessing.

Comment: I use fork, but it worked with printf

Comment: You need to post all relevant code. There is nothing inherently wrong with the code you posted. (Also, where is 'c' printed?)

Comment: Well, my problem has been "solved". I had special case of input data, for which the output was in wrong order, otherwise it's working fine. However, thanks for your help!

Comment: barber & customer sounds suspiciously like we're missing a homework tag.

Comment: This sounds like you're trying to roll your own threads with `fork`. Note that there is no synchronization/locking on the output since each process has its own copy of memory and its own copy of the `FILE` buffers.

Answer (score 2):

(Can't comment, must answer...)

No, it isn't that printf/fprintf buffer differently, the FILE* object is the same if you do fprintf(stdout, ...) or printf(....).

Several processes are writing to the same file, and as a result of no synchronization and differing buffering in each process the output is messed up.

Answer (score 1):

printf and fprintf will have different device driver buffering.

As you say you're using fork, and based on the output, I'm inferring the code is similar to

1. Open file
2. Fork
3. Write the data

In this case, the different order crops up because the write is happening in random order, depending on when each child process gets scheduled.

The simplest solution is just wrap the app in a shell script, and run the binary through [tee](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tee_%28command%29) - that way everything you log to stdout also goes to file.

If you need a more complex solution, you'll need to set up an IPC mechanism between the processes, and do all the writes in the parent.

One approach is to set stdout to a pipe (from [socketpair](http://linux.die.net/man/2/socketpair)) before you fork, and read from the pipe in the parent process (using select() to avoid blocking), then log to screen/file. You'll need to dup() stdout before using freopen to avoid losing it. I've probably missed a few things, as I haven't done this for a while.